# facebook php $facebook->getLoginUrl email user_location no effect

Tags: php, facebook

Using the latest Facebook PHP SDK 3

I want to get access to email and possibly user_location, however, when I use the following code, it gets to the Request for Permission page, but I don't see email or user_location listed.......just the normal one that says "Access my basic information'

```
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email, user_location'));
```

then

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

also doesn't return the email...

could someone give me some idea what might be the problem?

I GOT IT

got it, it needs to be 'scope' PHP SDK 3, NOT 'req_perms' =)

Comment: Perhaps Facebook has decided to not give access to email adresses anymore due to the risk of spamming. I remember reading a comment about this somewhere. In passing, I'm not familiar enough with the SDK to know whether this information *should* be accessible with extended permissions.

Comment: I am pretty sure I could, I looked at couple sites that are doing it. I just can't see the code cuz its PHP =P Must be some syntax or app setup on the facebook side perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to ask extended permission to get the email address of a user. In the permissions "Scope", included "email" in the array like:

```
    $params = array(
  'scope' => 'email, read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

This works for me with php sdk